# Is it possible to rename Wordpress native sub-sitemap (with Yoast SEO plugin installed)?

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I have a WP website with the Yoast SEO plugin installed. I need to add a new post type, coincidentally named `author`. Changing it is highly undesirable due to business logic. The problem occurred during the sitemap generation process - native WP users in the admin area are included in the `/author-sitemap.xml` sitemap, and for this post type, `/author-sitemap.xml` is also generated. As a result, in addition to two sub-sitemaps with the same names in the general sitemap.xml, the second one also overwrites the first one in content, so there are two identical sub-sitemaps with the same names and content in the general sitemap.

Question: Is it possible to rename the sitemap of native users to, say, `/users-sitemap.xml` and how to do it? Are there any filter-hooks for the Yoast SEO plugin?

[Wordpress sitemap with two identical sub-sitemaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS6cp.png)